# Is it possible to build a query that does the update first with where and join conditions and if update exists then inserts?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I need to update a table which has been joined with several tables to extract the data and if the update fails then inserts the data in a new row... 
currently I have a update query

.....

and I am thinking if the above query fails it should insert

```
INSERT INTO ASSET_ASSOCIATION.....
```

Thanks ...

Comment: have a look at the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to give you a full answer with the limited details above, but as Loopo says you can use *INSERT....ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE* . For example, based on your UPDATE:-

```
INSERT INTO ASSET_ASSOCIATION(ASSET_ID, ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID, ASSET_FIELD_ID)
SELECT a.ID, b.ID, 46
FROM ASSET a
INNER JOIN HD_TICKET ON HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE2 = a.NAME
INNER JOIN USER U ON U.ID = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID
INNER JOIN ASSET b ON U.FULL_NAME LIKE BINARY CONCAT('%',b.NAME,'%') AND b.NAME <> ''
WHERE ASSET.ASSET_TYPE_ID = 5 
AND HD_TICKET.ID = 120
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID=VALUES(ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID)
```

This is assuming you have a unique key on asset_id and asset_field_id. However almost certain your table is more complex than this.